# Do mosfets without protection diode exist?

Tags: mosfet

If they do exist, what is advantage of using them? How often are they used in comparison with mosfets that have integrated diode?

Comment: Which diode? The intrinsic body diode, or the extra ESD protection?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "protection diode"? Are you referring to a gate-source  zener or to the parasitic body diode?

Comment: I mean diode between drain and source.

Comment: That diode is intrinsic to the mosfet structure and cannot be removed. It's not a part that's intentionally added.

Comment: The body diode of a mosfet (the diode from source to drain) is a parasitic effect, or feature if you will, of the way the mosfet is build up. You cannot make a mosfet (with current technology) which does not have a body diode, so no they don't exist and are hence never used.

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks a lot, I was little bit confused why it was there and thought it was some sort of protection.

Comment: It's worth mentioning also that the diode isn't _technically_ between drain and source; there are two diodes, one between drain and body and one between source and body. In most cases, but not all, body and source are internally connected together, so the source-body diode is shorted out and the drain-body diode becomes effectively a drain-source diode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible to manufacture 4-lead MOSFETs with the body connection (aka "back gate") brought out, but I think they are pretty rare.

You'll see parts with the body not tied to source used in chips, for example to make a good [transmission gate](https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT4066.pdf).

[image]

In the above, when the body is tied to Vcc the diode junction does not become forward biased until the voltage exceeds Vcc, allowing the TG to pass signals over the whole GND to Vcc range.

Comment: Can you clarify here? The NMOS body voltage must not exceed ground+Vd and the PMOS body must be greater than Vcc-Vd, I think. Assuming that at least one PMOS source is connected to Vcc and one NMOS source is connected to ground.